# showing confirmation message using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Good day all, I'm new to CodeIgniter and I really need some help. I'm trying to make a confirmation message(div id="delmsg") using jquery when deleting a mysql record. But only the delete operation works but I don't see any message.

Code for `Model` page:

```
function delete_post($postID)
{
    $this->db->where('post_id', $postID);
    $this->db->delete('khanposts');
}
```

Code for `Controller` page:

```
function deletepost($postID)
{
    $this->khanpost->delete_post($postID);
    redirect(base_url().'khanposts/index/');
}
```

Code for `View` page:

```
<div id="main_body">
if (!isset($posts)){
echo "<p>There are currently no active posts.</p>";
}else{
echo '<table align="center">';
echo '<tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Contact No.</th><th>Actions</th></tr>';
foreach ($posts as $row){
    echo '<tr><td><i>' .$row['email']. '</i></td><td><b>' .$row['contact']. '</b></td>
    <td><a href="' .base_url(). 'khanposts/deletepost/' .$row['post_id']. '" id="delete"><i>Delete</i></a></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table><br><br>';
echo '<br><br><div id="delmsg"></div>';
}
</div>

<script>
$('#delete').click(function() {
$("#delmsg").css("visibility", "visible");
$('<h3>Record Deleted!</h3>').appendTo('#main_body');
});
//return false;
});
</script>
```

Is there any way that I could use jquery message in codeigniter? And also do I've to load any jquery plugin file manually in codeigniter? Any help would be grateful. Tnx.

Comment: You shouldn't show your "record deleted!" message after the user clicks the button; you should only show it after the delete code has successfully run.

Comment: @Blazemonger, ok then how can i do it like u said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your'e redirecting the page, clicking on a link, in this situation you should show the delete confirmation message when you land back to the posts page:

```
function deletepost($postID)
{
    $this->khanpost->delete_post($postID);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('delmsg', 'Record Deleted!'); //this sets a one time accessable flash data
    redirect(base_url().'khanposts/index/');
}
```

Now, to show this message in your view:

```
echo '<br><br><div id="delmsg"><h3>'.$this->session->flashdata('delmsg').'</h3></div>';
```

Comment: I tried flashdata before but for some reason didn't work. Maybe I was doing wrong. But this worked like a charm. TnQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by an Ajax call, you shouldn't show deleted message until you get success return from your request, and you need to use jQuery library to do that, Codeigniter itself doesn't provide you this, so you have to import jQuery in your view file like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To make an Ajax call, add a data attribute which will hold the id of the that item and remove the href attribute as this will make your page to go to that page if you don't prevent that, also id tags must be unique so change it to class:

```
foreach ($posts as $row){
    echo '<tr><td><i>' .$row['email']. '</i></td><td><b>' .$row['contact']. '</b></td>
    <td><a data-id="' .$row['post_id']. '" href="#" class="delete"><i>Delete</i></a></td></tr>';
}
```

Then, make the Ajax call like this:

```
$(".delete").on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo site_url('khanposts/deletepost');?>",
         type: 'POST',
         data: { "post_id": $(this).data("id") },
         success: function() {
             $("#delmsg").css("visibility", "visible");
             $('<h3>Record Deleted!</h3>').appendTo('#main_body');
         }
     });
 });
```

Then in your controller, get the post value like this, both the ajax method or browsing that page method can work if we configure it like this :

```
function deletepost($postID = null, $redirect = true)
{
    if($postID == null){
        $postID =  $this->input->post('post_id');
        $redirect = false;
    }
    $this->khanpost->delete_post($postID);
    if($redirect)
        redirect(base_url().'khanposts/index/');
}
```

Comment: This ajax call is depended on POST type, but I'm working on a HTML link. Will it still work for the link?

Comment: I tried your code but nothing's working. Not even record gets deleted.

Comment: can you check the console log and write the output of your javascript call, as this should work.

Comment: Sorry to say but how can I do that?

Comment: ctrl + shift + j in firefox, see this for further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console, you will see what url returns when you post, just paste that log here.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < localhost/codeigniter/khanposts/index/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } localhost/codeigniter/khanposts/index/:81`

Comment: include the ajax part in a php file, not in a javascript file if you are doing, also use the latest jquery release which i wrote above as i don't know whether jquery 1.9.1 may be bugged or not, there may be many reasons of this error, also what do you have at khanposts controller line 81?